# How do I dynamically add to a JSON array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

So I have the following JSON:

```
[{"username":"User1","password":"Password"},
 {"username":"User5","password":"passWord"},]
```

Generated from:

```
<?php $username = $_POST["username"]; ?><br>
<?php $password = $_POST["password"]; ?><br>

<?php

    $currentData = file_get_contents('UserJSON.txt');
    $array_data = json_decode($currentData, true);
    $extra = array(
        'username' => $username, 
        'password' => $password
    );
    $array_data[] = $extra;
    $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
    if(file_put_contents('UserJSON.txt',$final_data)) {
        print("working");
    }

?>
```

After the user logs in they have the ability to make a post, how would I go about creating a post array for each user and how would I add to it dynamically ?

This is all I have and I have tried many different ways, but cant seem to figure out how to make it dynamic.

```
<?php
    $urlText = $_REQUEST["urlText"];
    $currentData = file_get_contents('UserJSON.txt');
    $array_data = json_decode($currentData, true);
    //for loop
    $array_data[i]['Posts'] = $urlText;
    //end for loop
    $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
    if(file_put_contents('UserJSON.txt',$final_data)) {
    }
?>
```

In this situation though, posts is not an array, it just simply overwrites what already there.

```
 [{"username":"User1","password":"Password","Posts:{"This is a post"}},
{"username":"User5","password":"passWord"},"Posts:{"This is a post2"}}]
```

Therefore, how do I add a posts array and how do I add to it dynamically ? I have not been able to figure such a simple thing out for a very long time

Comment: `$array_data[$i]['Posts'][] = $urlText; `

Comment: and maybe before that loop, `$array_data[$i]['Posts'] = [];`

Comment: Why are you doing this with JSON files? This really should be done using a database.

Comment: I am required to do it with json files @barmar

Comment: @dave how do I know what the last index is so that I can place I in it?

Comment: using json is the wrong tool for the job, but if you insist (ironic username ;p), once user logs in pull out the array by username based on session  (your using session right?)  or use individual json files for each user, which might be better because of file locking or memory issues which your eventually going to encounter

Comment: also dont store plaintext passwords.. once a bug, locking or memory issue shows path disclosure, a users just going to access the file and swipe all your usernames and passwords..

Comment: The approach is severely flawed.  As soon as you have a race condition that lets one user overwrite the file because another user's data is stale, you will see what I mean.  Totally non-`ACID`

Answer (score 0):

File get contents from like "posts/useridhere.txt", or allposts.txt

You will also need to use unique post IDs.

Json decode your posts JSON

Add post content to array

Json encode array

Write new json to the users post file

Ultimately I do not recommend this. If you want a paid internship I'll teach you how to use MySQL. We make websites :) but if you want to do it this way, you'll need a JSON file to store unique post IDs or even store all posts in one file. The problem is that you'll have a limit of how many posts can be stored in that single JSON array. I hope this answer is enough to help you. It's all the steps needed

```
$posts = file_get_contents($postsFile);
$posts = json_decode($posts);
$newPost = array(
"user"=>$user,
"postTitle"=>$string,
"text"=>$content
);
$posts[] = $newPost; 
$newPostID = count($posts); // will not work properly (for linking posts) once you delete a post - you need unique post ids generated! 
$posts = json_encode($posts); 
// Overwrite your posts file with $posts. It will have all posts you need :)
```

Comment: You can't store all the posts in one file, as there will quickly be a race condition because it's no were close to [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) complaint.   What will happen eventually, is two processes will open the file read the data, one will do it's update, then the second, but because there is no concurrency checks and no transaction logs the second process will overwrite the data from the first process and it will be lost.  That is pretty much a given.

Comment: Correct, there's a whole long list of reasons to not store data as JSON like this, but a separate file for each post is also not that great either. And it can still be nulled out just like a global file or file for each user :/